# (Контекст) Как сделать, чтобы при клике на элементе <div> картинка менялась на другую(только css)?

Tags: css, img, веб-дизайн, radio

Есть код(ниже). Как сделать, чтобы при клике картинка менялась на другую?

```css
.feature-block {
  width: 270px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.feature-block-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 35px auto 0;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.feature-block-line {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #EDEDED;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}
.feature-block-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
}
.feature-block p {
  margin: 20px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: "Roboto Light";
  font-size: 12px;
}
#block-radio-1 {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label .feature-block {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00B533;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="block-radio-1" name="block-select">
<label for="block-radio-1">
  <div class="feature-block">
    <div class="feature-block-header">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Simbolo_konoha.svg" class="feature-block-img" alt="">


      <div class="feature-block-line"></div>
      <p class="feature-block-title">Title</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить на страницу две картинки, одну прятать - другую показывать. При клике - первую показать, вторую спрятать.

```css
.feature-block {
  width: 270px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.feature-block-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 35px auto 0;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.feature-block-line {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #EDEDED;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}
.feature-block-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto Regular";
  font-size: 16px;
}
.feature-block p {
  margin: 20px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: "Roboto Light";
  font-size: 12px;
}
#block-radio-1 {
  display: none;
}
.checked-img {
display: none;
}
input:checked + label .feature-block {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00B533;
}

input:checked + label .checked-img{
display: block;
}

input:checked + label .unchecked-img{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="block-radio-1" name="block-select">
<label for="block-radio-1">
  <div class="feature-block">
    <div class="feature-block-header">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Simbolo_konoha.svg" class="feature-block-img unchecked-img" alt="">


<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/505px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png" class="feature-block-img checked-img">
      <div class="feature-block-line"></div>
      <p class="feature-block-title">Title</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```